# Nested anonymous function call doesn't update the call to find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a nested call to the same function via an anonymous call. The element under el is expected to be updated by something else but while it has the .updating class, should keep calling itself. Once this find() returns false, execute the else. The problem is even though the .updating is gone because some other code has removed it, the find is still returning true, so it loops indefinitely. Or is there a better way to do this (Edit: is there a better way to do the entire thing) ? Ideally it should only be 1 call / nest, and if .updating class is still there, the call just sleeps for a certain interval.

```
    this.TryClick = function (el) {
        if ($(el).find('.updating')) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                self.TryClick(el);
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            const btn = $(el).find('.myclass');
            btn.click();
        }
    };
```

Comment: jQuery's `find` will always return a truthy value even if no elements found

Comment: try doing `$(el).find('.updating').length > 0`

Comment: or just `$(el).find('.updating').length` :p

Comment: You might be looking for `$(el).is('.updating')` or `.has('.updating')`. The `find` method returns a (truthy) collection

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work

To check if any elements were found, you should use the length property of the result set.

```
this.TryClick = function (el) {
const updatingElements = $(el).find('.updating');

if (updatingElements.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        self.TryClick(el);
    }, 1000);
} else {
    const btn = $(el).find('.myclass');
    btn.click();
}
};
```

Now, the condition **updatingElements.length** will correctly check if there are any elements with the class '**updating**'. If the length is greater than zero, it will continue the loop; otherwise, it will execute the else block. This should help you avoid the infinite loop issue.

Comment: Thank you and to all who replied. It is indeed the truthiness returned by find() and has got nothing to do with nesting and anonymous function.